# Best way to handle re rendering components inside render method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a component,assume(Login).When i sent the request  to server,i am fetching response(eventually i am getting the data in terms of props to my Login Component).Form props i need to validate ,to which component ,i allow the user.The below thing what i am doing so far,please update me the best approach

See, this is what i am doing so far

```
    render()
{

       const {status}=this.props;
       if(status===1){
          return (<X/>)
       } else {
          return (<X/>
       }
}
```

Comment: Please try to ask clearer questions also! This is a bit hard to understand :)

Comment: You added the label react-redux have you implemented Redux into the rest of your project yet?

Comment: @ShaneG what else you need to understand ?

Comment: @TRINADHKOYA No i understand it fine i think. its just the English and the punctuation makes it a bit hard to follow. If my answer below solves your problem, please mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to re-render components that are inside your render method, place the data you are using for those components in a state object:

```
state = {
 myStatus: status
}
```

Then call your data in your render method from State:

```
render() {
   if(this.state.myStatus === 1){
      return (<X/>)
   } else {
      return (<X/>)
   }
}
```

Then to re-render this data, just call setState:

```
this.setState({
 myStatus: 1
});
```

This will automatically re-render. Call setState whereever you are calling your data. Hope this helps!